# SQL Select Query Group By With Key (Join or SubQuery)

Tags: sql

Trying to wrap my head around this query but here it is...

Table: TVEpisode
Columns: TVEpisodeID (PK), TVSeriesID, season (number), episode (number), watched (0 or 1)

What I am looking to get is the first unwatched (value 0) episode for each TVSeries.  For example, if I have watched all of season 1 for a TVSeriesID (45) and my lasted watched episode is season 2 episode 5, I want the query to return:

```
TVEpisodeID | TVSeriesID | Season | Episode
PK          | 45         | 2      | 6
```

Need that result for each TVSeries

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as well formatted text. Also show us your current query attempt.

Comment: And please tell us what database you are using (MySQL, SQL Server, etc.).

Comment: Database is SQL Server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In most databases, you would do this with the ANSI standard window functions:

```
select tve.*
from (select tve.*
             row_number() over (partition by tvseriesid order by season, episode) as seqnum
      from tvepisode tve
      where tve.watched = 0
     ) tve
where seqnum = 1;
```

I assume that "first" is referring to the combination of `season` and `episode`.

Answer (score 0):

This should give you first `watched=0` of all season/episode combination

```
SELECT *
FROM TVEpisode
WHERE TVEpisodeID IN
    ( SELECT min(TVEpisodeID)
     FROM TVEpisode
     WHERE watched=0
     GROUP BY TVSeriesID) t
```

Comment: This will fail in sql server (and probably other databases as well), since you have columns in the select list that does not appear in the group by clause.

Comment: Oh yeah. Thanks, I didnt need those columns anyway in inner query. Thats why I used outer query

Comment: This assumes TVEpisodeID to have the same order of values as season and episode combined. This is not mentioned in the query.

Comment: No it doesn't. TVEpisodeID is a surrogate key in the question

Comment: what if you have 2 unwatched records for the same TVSeriesID, one with TVEpisodeID = 4, episode  = 3 and the other with TVEpisodeID = 3,  episode  = 4? In such a case your query will return the wrong result...

Comment: Ok I understand what you are saying. Yes I am assuming that episodes of a series are inserted in an order.